# Don't find element in data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this js code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {id: id, 'YII_CSRF_TOKEN': token },
    success: function(data) {
        var content = $(data).find('.content');
        console.log(content);
        $('.content').html(content);
    }
}).error(function() {
    console.log('Error!');
})
```

Data in console.log():

```
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[27], context: undefined, selector: ".content", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

My content do not get inserted. If I try:

```
$('.content').html('TEST');
```

It does work.
I think it is the problem with jQuery objects.

Comment: what is the contents of `data`

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: @Johny If you understand, http://pastebin.com/pDhsdLg7 ;)

Answer (score 1):

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) accepts a string as an argument, in your case `content` is a jquery object, so you need to use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append an element.

```
$('.content').empty().append(content);
```

Comment: `content.clone()` might be more appropriate

Comment: @JanDvorak you mean `replace()`?

Comment: I am tryed. My content retired and nothing add. Like `$('.content').html(content);`

Comment: @JanDvorak like `$('.content').replaceWith(content);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny good point. What about `content.clone().contents().appendTo('.content')`?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think we can go as long as we want with the variations